# SDL Resolution issue

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, resolution

After using SDL for a bit, I found a small issue.
When setting the video mode in full screen:

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BITDEPTH,FLAGS);
```

With the flags:

```
const Uint32 Graphics::FLAGS = SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF |SDL_FULLSCREEN;
```

The screen goes to fullscreen like it should.
But when the game is finished, the resolution of the monitor keeps the resolution of the game (in my case 800x600) instead of returning to what it was before the game.
Is there anyway code-wise I can fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a small example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Sure, give me a quick minute (project with this issue is somewhat larger).

Comment: Found the issue when I tried the small example. I forgot to include SDL_Quit(), which meant that my program would exit "cleanly" without running SDL's cleanup stuff (such as fixing the resolution).
Would write it as my own answer, but it won't let me for 7 hours. Copy/paste and it's all yours.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the end of processing, free the memory with the data from your block, something like SDL_Quit() or SDL_FreeSurface(), if you didn't.